# husband-and-wife team or husband and wife team?

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is it necessary to use a hyphen in writing a compound word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-a-hyphen-in-writing-a-compound-word)

Referring to a sentence from an online magazine:

"Lonely Planet was started in 1975, when the British hippie ***husband-and-wife*** team Maureen and Tony Wheeler self-published a guide to cheap travel in Southeast Asia."

I have noticed that in other resources also: that ***"husband-and-wife***" team is used instead of **"husband and wife**" team.

What is the right usage?

Comment: It is a style issue. Associated Press style would be to hyphenate a compound modifier like this.

Comment: [This answers your question.](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/51690/14073)