# When to hyphenate open-form compound nouns

Tags: nouns, hyphenation, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I hyphenate an open-form compound word with another that should be hyphenated?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51665/how-do-i-hyphenate-an-open-form-compound-word-with-another-that-should-be-hyphen)

I am taking an editing course, and the instructor said that the following phrase must be hyphenated and that I was wrong in not hyphenating it:

*row-house kitchen*

I did not hyphenate *row house* in this phrase, since I thought that it was clear that the kitchen belonged to the row house. To me, it seems a bit silly to presume that the reader would be confused here. (However, I have lived in a row house in D.C., so perhaps I am biased.)

Must *row house* be hyphenated in this instance? If so, then must, for example, *free*[-]*trade agreement* or *post*[-]*office box* be hyphenated? This seems excessive. I searched several periodicals, and these phrases appear without hyphens more often than with hyphens.

I see that there is guidance [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-a-hyphen-in-writing-a-compound-word) and [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51665/how-do-i-hyphenate-an-open-form-compound-word-with-another-that-should-be-hyphen), and I understand that one should employ a hyphen to improve readability where necessary, but I am having trouble understanding when and when not to hyphenate an open-form compound noun. Is this more of a style preference? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You did OK with "open-form compound noun" ...

Comment: Don't think of it as a **rule** - think of it as a **courtesy** and a **precaution**. *Anything which can be misunderstood will be.*

Comment: If your instructor actually said that you were **wrong** in not hyphenating _row house kitchen_, he was wrong. He could legitimately have said, "That's not our preferred way here," but has no right to enforce debated rules arbitrarily. Mind you, if I were under his authority, I'd do it his / her way until it was safe to choose another style guide. Balanced articles appear at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_compounds#Hyphenated_compound_modifiers and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_modifier .

Answer (score 5):

I presume your instructor is using the rule: "hyphenate an open-form compound noun when it is used as an adjective preceding the noun it modifies." Not everybody agrees with this rule, but you can find it [online](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/576/01/).

From the above link:

> Use a hyphen to join two or more words serving as a single adjective before a noun:
>     - a one-way street
>   - chocolate-covered peanuts
>   - well-known author
>   However, when compound modifiers come after a noun, they are not hyphenated:
>   - The peanuts were chocolate covered.
>   - The author was well known.

If you are writing for a publication where this is in the style guide, or taking a course where the instructor believes in this rule, you should probably follow it.