# Swiss made or Swiss-made? Swiss quality or Swiss-quality

Tags: grammar, hyphenation

As indicated above, do we need to hyphenate said words?

The same questions apply to other "country-related terms" like Singapore quality, German precision, etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I noticed the compound words didn't include "country-related" choices.

Comment: Please visit [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51665/how-do-i-hyphenate-an-open-form-compound-word-with-another-that-should-be-hyphen). Please search before posting any question.

Comment: The product reflects Swiss quality.  The Swiss-made watch is still running.

Answer (score 0):

Compound adjectives preceding a noun are hyphenated as per the clever above examples. (Chicago Manual of Style). However be wary of compound nouns which are only hyphenated if it says so in your dictionary. "I love German choolate cake." But "German-made German chocolate cake tastes better in French-style cafes fronted by Roman arches with concrete-stamped roman font."
However, if there will be confusion to the reader then hyphenate: "German chocolate cake drizzled with German-pancake batter is really the best!"