# Is it "real-estate-specific" or "real estate-specific"?

Tags: grammar

Which of the phrases in the title is the correct adjective? Do I need to concatenate "real" and "estate" with a hyphen before appending "specific" to the two-word noun?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I hyphenate an open-form compound word with another that should be hyphenated?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51665/how-do-i-hyphenate-an-open-form-compound-word-with-another-that-should-be-hyphen)

Comment: The above link should be a help, but if it doesn't provide enough information, consider providing a full sentence. The best solution may depend on exactly how you're using the phrase "real estate-specific"/"real estate specific".

Comment: (For those who eschew the dual hyphen/dash usage for multiple instances): There will be at least garden-path inconvenience if you don't include the hyphen after 'real'. Adding one before 'specific' is usual. I'd use two here.