# Three-word compound adjectives that look awful

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated, suspended-hyphen

One English rule is to hyphenate two or more words when they come before a noun they modify and act as a single idea, called a **compound adjective**. This is the most common use of the hyphen I've seen. For example:

> A non-cloud platform
> Some cloud-based platforms

What happens when there are three adjectives before a noun? Should I hyphenate all three? This example looks awful, but maybe that's because it's joining two **compound adjectives** that we usually see by themselves:

> Non-cloud-based platform

That compound adjective would look better without the two hyphens.

For most groups of three or more hyphenated words, they tend to form **expressions** that behave like compound adjectives, e.g. up-to-date, hit-or-miss, trial-and-error, etc. but they would also look alright as phrases by themselves. The three-word compound adjective in my example doesn't fall into that category.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be more about aesthetics than grammar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I hyphenate an open-form compound word with another that should be hyphenated?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51665/how-do-i-hyphenate-an-open-form-compound-word-with-another-that-should-be-hyphen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Grammarly suggests](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/en-dash/) that in this case, as well as when one of the adjectives in the compound is multiple *non-hyphenated* words, you should use an **en dash** to separate the two 'highest-level' halves, like this:

> non–cloud-based platform.

This was mentioned in a [related question here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51665), but a comment indicates that the "tyranny of the typewriter", among other misfortunes, has precluded its widespread adoption.

Comment: Please vote to close duplicates rather than answering them.